# TailwindCSS Trying to style all children by the last element

Tags: tailwind-css

I've got a requirement that from a parent element, I need to style all the child elements with a margin expect the last one.

I'm struggling to accomplish this with Tailwind and attached a fiddle with my attempt using arbitary values.

```
<div class="flex items-center [&>*]:mr-2 [&>*:last]:mr-0">
 <button class="bg-red-500">
   One
 </button>
 <button class="bg-green-500">
   Two
 </button>
 <button class="bg-blue-500">
   etc.
 </button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjrobinson/ag9kz6jf/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run you code on https://play.tailwindcss.com/ it's working as expected, I believe.

However, I'd suggest you use the `gap` property (using the `gap-{number}` class) to achieve the result you want in a more descriptive and direct manner:

```
<div class="flex items-center gap-2">
 <button class="bg-red-500">
   One
 </button>
 <button class="bg-green-500">
   Two
 </button>
 <button class="bg-blue-500">
   etc.
 </button>
</div>
```

Result will be:

[image]